# Getting from OBS/Xsplit to HTML5

Tags: html, rtmp

I am but a meager systems guy and this seems to be a programmer's domain so be gentle. This is my first post on this site.

I work at a high school and for our presentation software for announcements and such we use XSplit. This is similar to OBS and allows us to use a green screen. To share it with the rest of the users on the network, XSplit has a built in webserver which lets users visit a persistent URL and view the the live stream in Flash.

Since Flash is now slowly being shunned by Chrome and will likely go that way with all browsers, the logical next step for anything using Flash seems to be to get to HTML5.

So here I am, trying to get from Point A (OBS/XSplit/presentation software), to Point B (HTML5 code on a website doing .

OBS and XSplit can be output to existing streaming services like Twitch, YouTube, etc. but these lack certain privacy requirements, or persistent url requirements we have. Alternatively you can output to RTMP, but this of course cannot be fed directly into HTML5.

I believe I have to get my RTMP stream somehow converted into something else before I can plug it into HTML5, but not sure what the best thing to use is, and how much coding I would have to do, as I am not a coder.

There is another thread on this, but doesn't have a whole lot of info for dummies like me. Has anyone here successfully accomplished what I'm describing? Or know of a tutorial for this adventure?

Thanks

Comment: Have you spoken to xsplit directly to see if its possible without any complicated extra work? It's possible that they might have something in the works already. Additionally, its possible to make the streams private n youtube where only [those with the link can watch the streams](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/157177)

Comment: I have talked to XSplit a while ago and they do not offer any alternatives at the moment. I recently posed the question to the OBS forums as well but haven't gotten an answer yet. As for YouTube, I looked into that and it does have a mechanism for keeping things private, but as far as I can see you have to continually make an event each time you want to stream, and reinvite all the members. This is a bit of a task for a busy principal to do this every time and invite a ton of teachers. Correct though on the YouTube bit if I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: there are 3 states of privacy for youtube videos. Private is as you just mentioned, unlisted is "public" but not shown in searches or the channels list and is only accessible via a link (which would work out the same as you have now, only internet based vs lan based). Sadly the only way to shorten the process with private videos and adding users is for everyone to be using google accounts (which is a waste of time really unless your school uses google apps as their provider) after which you can create a circle that cascades the invites

Comment: When you are broadcasting the videos themselves, is it a live stream or a pre recorded video that can be accessed whenever you want?

Comment: If only it were pre-recorded is wouldn't be so bad, the streaming is what makes it difficult. As for the YouTube thing, as far as I can see, again you have to prerecord the video/finish the stream in order to set privacy settings. Not sure how to set it so I can just start a stream whenever and people can get at. Seems like you must make the stream, then invite, every time.

Answer (score 0):

This will be difficult to do without a coding background, or budget to use a commercial product. What you need to do however is set up and nginx server with the rtmp module, use that to convert rtmp to dash, then use something like dash.js, to build a web player. There are may places online that describe how to do this.

Comment: I can code a little, just not without the assistance of some sort of walkthrough. I already set up nginx and rtmp on ubuntu and got it to work, it's really that next step that I'm having trouble finding a walkthrough for that's simple enough me.

Comment: Why didn't you put in your question that you have already set up Nguni? Does it work? Are you generating segments and manifests? Stack overflow is not a service to have custom tutorials written for your specific case. If your question requires more that on paragraph to answer, narrow the question. Vague incomplete questions will get vague incomplete answers.

Comment: As I mentioned this is my first post so I'm not too experienced even with what is the appropriate way to request stuff here. It is does work in that I can view my stream via rtmp://localhost through VLC, but I need to embed it in a webpage but not with Flash. I think nginx can output HLS so I might try down that road. Yeah I kind of figured this place is a little over my head but thought I'd try. I'll keep Googling

Comment: Did you read my answer, and google the parts you didn't understand (like dash.js)?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, well, I figured it out. It's probably not the cleanest way to do it, but it's a 'for dummies' way of doing it without having to get into too much coding/command line. Here it is for anyone who lacks coding skill but would like to accomplish what I was asking about:

1. First of all follow this guide https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/how-to-set-up-your-own-private-rtmp-server-using-nginx.50/ to get to the point where you have your OBS/XSplit type software viewable as rtmp://yourip in VLC
2. In VLC, using the Stream feature where you pick your rtmp://yourip as your source, and HTTP as the destination, and Theora + Vorbis (OGG) as your selection for the stream to be transcoded to.
3. Simply take your new http://yourip:8080 stream and plunk it into a 
   video width="720" src="http://yourip:8080" autoplay
   type="video/ogg; codes=theora" /video" or something similar and you should be able to play it in Chrome, at least. (Dunno how to post that with the < things)

I'm sure there's some optimization to be done but seems to play pretty well.

Again, probably better ways to do it especially if you're dealing with people using different browsers/mobile devices, etc. But for my purposes where I just need to get a bunch of people on a local network using Chrome to view a stream which isn't Flash based, this does the trick.